# CSS doesn't change size with purifycss-webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I need to use the plugin purifycss-webpack, but I'm not so familiar with js, so, I think I don't use it as it should.

I use a template, so I have a lot of LESS files, compiled in a big CSS File, and I need to remove all unused generated CSS.

I use Laravel / Laravel Mix / Webpack to do it. Here is an extract of my webpack.mix.js

```
const {mix} = require('laravel-mix');
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const PurifyCSSPlugin = require('purifycss-webpack');

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallbackLoader: 'style-loader',
                    loader: 'css-loader'
                })
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[contenthash].css'),
        // Make sure this is after ExtractTextPlugin!
        new PurifyCSSPlugin({
            // Give paths to parse for rules. These should be absolute!
            paths: glob.sync(path.join(__dirname, 'app/*.html')),
        })
    ]
};

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.combine([
    'resources/assets/less/bootstrap.less',
    'resources/assets/less/core.less',
    'resources/assets/less/components.less',
    'resources/assets/less/colors.less'

], 'resources/assets/less/main.less');

mix.less('resources/assets/less/main.less','css/main.css' );

mix.combine([
     'public/css/main.css',
    'resources/assets/css/custom.css',
    'resources/assets/css/protip.css',
    'resources/assets/css/nunito.css'
], 'public/css/app.css');
```

Webpack is getting me a Build OK, but I have a lot of unused CSS that is not removed...
Also removed

`entry: {...},
output: {...},`

because I didn't really know what to put here.

Any idea what am I doing wrong???

Comment: pass: purifyOptions: {info: true} to your `new PurifyCSSPlugin` and what is the output of that ?

Comment: ??? why not valid? It comes from docs: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/purifycss-webpack

Comment: I understand this is the entry point and the output folder, but I don't really understand the use case, as it should scan all process css no? It should replace original css by purified css, so it doesn't need this config

Comment: oh sorry about that, I was mislead because of the wrong indentation. Code is correct of course.

Comment: ooo. ok, fixed. I will try the purifyOption!

Comment: No output :( It seems it doesn't even get called.